# filter_var_array() - Undefined Variable

Tags: php, arrays, callback

I'm trying to use `filter_var_array()` and `FILTER_CALLBACK` to format some numbers, I thought this would work, but it does not:

```
$item_arr = filter_var_array($item_arr, array(
    'item_number'       => array(
        'filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options'   => array($this, 'number_format')
    )
) );
```

though this does work:

```
$item_arr = filter_var_array($item_arr, array(
    'item_number'       => array(
        'filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options'   => function( $num ){
            return number_format( $num );
        }
    )
) );
```

What's the difference between these two? What's the point of assigning an `array()` to options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are trying to create a callback for `$this->number_format`, but I guess you want the global function `number_format` instead. If you passing a function (unlike an object method) as callback just the function name as a string should getting passed, like this:

```
$item_arr = filter_var_array($item_arr, array(
    'item_number'       => array(
        'filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options'   => 'number_format'
    )
));
```

Check the documentation page about [`callbacks`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) to get more information.

---

If you want to format an array of numbers, the function [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) seems fitting better:

```
array_walk($item_arr, 'number_format');
```